# How do I display JButtons and JLabels in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jlabel

I tried to use this code to display a labeled window, but it only displays a blank window.

```
    JFrame window = new JFrame("My Window");
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setResizable(true);
    window.setSize(680,420);
    window.setContentPane(new Container());
    window.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("LABEL");
    label.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    panel.add(label);
    window.add(panel);
```

Comment: try window.setTital("My Window");

Comment: What you need to understand about `setVisible` is that it `paints` the frame and its components. If you set it visible before the components are added, it don't paint the components unitl another `paint` is called, like what you resize the frame. So logically, then, _"when should you call setVisible"?_

Answer (score 3):

Try calling `setVisible` last

```
JFrame window = new JFrame("My Window");
//window.setVisible(true);
//window.setResizable(true);
//window.setSize(680,420);
//window.setContentPane(new Container());
window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel label = new JLabel("LABEL");
label.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
panel.add(label);
window.add(panel);

window.setResizable(true);
// Pack will size the window to fit the content, 
// tacking into account the preferred size of the
// content...
window.pack();
window.setVisible(true);
```

Also note, `JLabel` is transparent by default, so setting it's background color will have no effect unless you change it's `opaque` property to `true`

Answer (score 1):

After adding all `component`, `set` the `visibility` of `frame`.

```
    JFrame window = new JFrame("My Window");
    window.setResizable(true);
    window.setSize(680,420);
    window.setContentPane(new Container());
    window.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("LABEL");
    label.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    panel.add(label);
    window.add(panel);     
    window.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

(as you are calling setvisible() method at starting)..
You can also use update() method so that the components on the jframe will be updated or repainted..